# React - cursor pointer in component and child without directly CSS

Tags: reactjs, cursor, styled-components

I'd like some help to implement a simple cursor pointer ( **hand** )  in a card (and affect all child components ) . I can't use directly css, only styled component and/or inline style.
my code: [All code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/afs-react-cursor-pointer-child?file=child1.jsx)

**I'd like to do some like in my parent component:**

```
<div id="box" style={cursorPointerThatAffecAllChild}>
```

**or similar**

[image]

**Parent component**
    ...

```
render() {
    return (
      <div id="box"> 
        <p style={{fontWeight:'800'}}>
          My card
        </p> 
         <Child1 > </Child1>
         <p>
         some text in parent
        </p>  
      </div>
    );
...
```

**child**

```
...
 return (
      <div>  
        <button  > My button on child 1 </button> 
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <span style={{color:'blue'}}> a span inside Child 1 </span>
       </div> 
    );
...
```

Comment: Your code link is broken

Comment: Where's the cursor pointer styles?

Comment: Is a simple cursos pointer  ( hand )

Comment: ... except the question is about how to apply that style and you omitted the part that is the style itself. you should be able to do `style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}`. verify you typed it correctly and that theres no syntax errors.

Comment: This really seems like a job for CSS. Is there a reason you can't use CSS for it considering you have a `styles.css` folder in your project?

Comment: I my real case I cant have a css file and need to use styled components or other approach.

Comment: Also what is the issue? in the stackblitz link the card already has cursor pointer?

Comment: It works in StackBlitz following the John Ruddell tip. In my real case don't and I'm cheking the difference.

Comment: That may have been me. I didn't realize that stackblitz was saving my tweaking in real time

Answer (score 2):

If you have to avoid css, you can use styled components and write the css there.

```
const MyCursorPointer = styled.div`
  cursor: pointer;

  * { /* this would be for elements that override the cursor pointer but are children of this component */
    cursor: pointer;
    /* cursor: pointer !important; */
    /*                      ^ Use this style if you still see a cursor other than type pointer on the children */
  }
`
```

If you want to do inline you could do this

```
<div style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>
```

but note elements that have a predefined `cursor` style may override this. the `styled-components` solution should enforce the pointer if thats what you want.